# Communication between two applications using Environment Variables

Tags: windows, windows-services, environment-variables, c++builder

### Question

How to communicate with another program (for instance, a windows service one) through environment variables (not system or user ones)?

### What do we have

Well, I have the following scheme for a data logger:

```
-------------------------          --------------------------------
| the things to measure |          | the things that do something |
-------------------------          --------------------------------
     |                                  ^
     | sensors                          | switches
     V                                  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|                     dedicated hardware                          |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
     | ^
     | |  serial communication 
     V |
---------------                                       -------------
|   Windows   | ------------------------------------> |   user    |
|   service   | <------------------------------------ | interface |
---------------           udp communication           -------------
                                                            |^  keyboard
                                                            V| and screen
                                                         --------
                                                         | user |
                                                         --------
```

On current development:

- windows service is always running when Windows is running
- user can open and close user interface (of course :p)
- windows service acquires data from sensors
- user interface automatic requests data to windows service every 100ms and shows it to user via udp communication through some implemented protocol (we call it `GetData()` command and response to it)
- user can send some other commands to change the data to acquire through implemented protocol (we call it `SetSensors()` command and response to it)

Both user interface and windows service are developed on Borland C+ Builder 6 and use NMUDP component, from FastNet tab, for UDP communication.

### What we are thinking to do

Because of some buffer issues and to free udp channel only for sending `SetSensors()`command and response to it, we are considering that instead of using `GetData()`:

- Windows service would get data from sensors and put them on environment variables
- the user interface would read them to show to user

### Scheme after doing what we are thinking

```
-------------------------          --------------------------------
| the things to measure |          | the things that do something |
-------------------------          --------------------------------
     |                                  ^
     | sensors                          | switches
     V                                  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|                     dedicated hardware                          |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
     | ^
     | |  serial communication 
     V |
---------------                                       -------------
|             | ------------------------------------> |           |
|             |         environment variables         |           |
|             |         (get data from sensors)       |           |
|   Windows   |                                       |   user    |
|   service   |                                       | interface |
|             |                                       |           |
|             | ------------------------------------> |           |
|             | <------------------------------------ |           |
---------------           udp communication           -------------
                        (send commands to service)          |^  keyboard
                                                            V| and screen
                                                         --------
                                                         | user |
                                                         --------
```

### Any way to do that?

We would not use system and user environment variables, because it writes on Windows Registry, i.e., it will save to hard drive and it gets more slow...

Comment: You cannot communicate with environment variables, a process can only update their local copy.  Use any of the process interop mechanisms available in Windows, like a socket, named pipe or memory mapped file.  No point in using UDP, use TCP so you get a delivery guarantee.  UDP isn't faster when it doesn't go out on a network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @HansPassant said, I cannot do that directly. Although I saw some ways to do that via memory mapped file, it is so easy only to add one more udp communication channel through other port. So:

```
-------------------------          --------------------------------
| the things to measure |          | the things that do something |
-------------------------          --------------------------------
     |                                  ^
     | sensors                          | switches
     V                                  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|                     dedicated hardware                          |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
     | ^
     | |  serial communication 
     V |
---------------                                       -------------
|             | ------------------------------------> |           |
|             |           udp communication (port 3)  |           |
|             |         (get data from sensors)       |           |
|   Windows   |                                       |   user    |
|   service   |                                       | interface |
|             |                             (port 1)  |           |
|             | ------------------------------------> |           |
|             | <------------------------------------ |           |
---------------           udp communication (port 2)  -------------
                        (send commands to service)          |^  keyboard
                                                            V| and screen
                                                         --------
                                                         | user |
                                                         --------
```

If someone provide a better solution, I'll mark it as solution in future.